# Running gunicorn behind nginx for a django application

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I have the following nginx configuration in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nginx.conf`

```
cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nginx.conf 
server {
    # Redirect all www.project.com requests to project.com
    listen 80;
    server_name www.******.co;
    return 301 http://*******.co$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen   80;
    server_name ******.co;
    location /admin/media/ {
        # this changes depending on your python version
        root /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/sos/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib;
    }
    location /static/admin {
        autoindex on;
        root  /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/sos/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib;
    }
    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
    expires max;
        alias /home/ubuntu/codebase/static_files/;
    }
    location / {
    # This section is to redirect all http traffic to https if desired
    # if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
    #   rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    # }

        client_max_body_size 5M;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300;
        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
    }
    # what to serve if upstream is not available or crashes
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /home/ubuntu/codebase/static_files/500.html;
}
```

I have installed `gunicorn` via `pip install gunicorn` and put that in django settings'   *installed_apps*.

As mentioned [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/)  I run python manage.py run_gunicorn it does not give any error, but when I open my site, I get

```
Welcome to nginx!

If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.
```

I am sure gunicorn is running because of the following -

**ps aux|grep gunicorn**

```
ubuntu    1819  0.0  0.4 121928 16944 ?        S    22:08   0:00 python manage.py run_gunicorn -D
ubuntu    1822  0.0  0.7 136264 29556 ?        S    22:08   0:00 python manage.py run_gunicorn -D
ubuntu    2017  0.0  0.0   8172   944 pts/3    S+   22:31   0:00 grep --color=auto gunicorn
```

Any idea, what is going wrong? I have been banging my head for the past 8 hours.

Comment: do you have a /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default by any chance? maybe that's overrwriting your config

Comment: You made my day man....ahhh eff me... 1000 upvotes to the above comment